# protobuf3, python - How to set element to map<string,OtherMessage> dict?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

When I tried to set element of a `map<string,Y> dict of X` 
ValueError raised.

> "Direct assignment of submessage not allowed"

My experiment code is

```
syntax = "proto3";

message X {
  map<string,Y> dict = 1;
}

message Y {
  int32 v = 1;
}
```

And python code

```
x = x_pb2.X()
y = x_pb2.Y()
x.data['a'] = y
```

then error raised

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 8, in <module>
    x.data['a'] = y
ValueError: Direct assignment of submessage not allowed
```

How can I work around this problem?

Comment: Where is `data` coming from here?!

Answer (score 9):

I guess this is optimal usage pattern

```
x = x_pb2.X()
x.data['a'].v = 1
```

And another option is using `CopyFrom`

```
x = x_pb2.X()
y = x_pb2.Y()
y.v=2
x.data['a'].CopyFrom(y)
```