# How to use a prototbuf map in Python?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

Given a proto definition

```
message EndpointResult {
    int32 endpoint_id = 1;
    // property id as key
    map<int32, TimeSeries> properties = 2;
}

message TimeSeries {
    repeated TimeEntry value = 2;
}

message TimeEntry {
    int32 time_unit = 1;
    float value = 2;
}
```

I wish to populate the map in the EndpointResult class. I have tried different approaches suggested in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated?csw=1#map-fields) but all raise a error for me.

Setting up a test class

```
end_point_rslt = nom.EndpointResult()
end_point_rslt.endpoint_id=0

ts = nom.TimeSeries()
te = ts.value.add()
te.time_unit = 0
te.value = 5.
```

Then trying the different approaches:

```
end_point_rslt.properties[0] = ts
```

> ValueError: Direct assignment of submessage not allowed

```
end_point_rslt.properties[0].submessage_field = ts
```

> AttributeError: Assignment not allowed (no field "submessage_field" in protocol message object).

```
end_point_rslt.properties.get_or_create(0)
end_point_rslt.properties[0] = ts
```

> ValueError: Direct assignment of submessage not allowed

```
end_point_rslt.properties.get_or_create(0)
end_point_rslt.properties[0].submessage_field = ts
```

> AttributeError: Assignment not allowed (no field "submessage_field" in protocol message object).

```
end_point_rslt.properties = {0 : ts}
```

> AttributeError: Assignment not allowed to repeated field "properties" in protocol message object.

```
end_point_rslt.properties.get_or_create(0)
end_point_rslt.properties = {0 : ts}
```

> TypeError: Can't set composite field

**Any example of how to use a protocol buffer map in python would be greatly appreciate!**

Comment: Thanks for the post. Great to know I am not the only one suffering from the pain

Comment: The experience is very catmario

Answer (score 11):

After staring at the docs, I realized that the problem was me assigning a class to the dictionary.

The correct syntax is

```
end_point_rslt = nom.EndpointResult()
end_point_rslt.endpoint_id=0
te = end_point_rslt.properties[0].value.add()
te.time_unit = 0
te.value = 5.
```

Comment: how to dynamically add a key - value to the map ? Python protobuf implementation is currently a joke ! spent hours trying to figure simple things out only to find it doesn't work!

Comment: This post has a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583468/protobuf3-python-how-to-set-element-to-mapstring-othermessage-dict

Answer (score 3):

A workaround with **Struct**

Instead of

```
message EndpointResult {
    int32 endpoint_id = 1;
    // property id as key
    map<int32, TimeSeries> properties = 2;
}
```

Use

```
message EndpointResult {
    int32 endpoint_id = 1;
    // property id as key
    google.protobuf.Struct properties = 2;
}
```

Initiate message using

```
properties = google.protobuf.struct_pb2.Struct()
properties[key1]=[TimeEntry(time_unit1, val1), TimeEntry(time_unit2, val2)...]
properties[key2]=[TimeEntry(time_unit3, val3)...]

EndpointResult(
    endpoint_id='1',
    properties=properties
)
```

I've had encountered many issues using map as well and find this solution works

Answer (score 2):

Don't see anyone suggest this here. But one way is to utilize protobuf's `CopyFrom` ([ref](https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/pythontutorial/)).

Example

```
end_point_rslt.properties[0].CopyFrom(ts)
```